# Preg_replace : "foo", "bar", "foo bar" and "bar foo"

Tags: php, html, regex

I use a regular expression to find some words, and do something with the words/strings.

My example :

I wan't to set `<strong>` tag with all words I find :

```
$string = 'Hello, there is foo, after there is bar but now I need foo bar.'

$html = preg_replace('/(foo|bar)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);

$html will be 'Hello, there is <strong>foo</strong>, after there is <strong>bar</strong> but now I need <strong>foo</strong> <strong>bar</strong>.'
```

And I wan't, if they are 1 word following 1 other word searched, that result :

```
'Hello, there is <strong>foo</strong>, after there is <strong>bar</strong> but now I need <strong>foo bar</strong>.'
```

How can I modify my regular expression to get the 2 words between us and work on it without separated tag ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$search = 'foo bar blah';
$string = 'Hello, there is foo, after there is bar but now I need foo bar blah.';

$search = preg_quote($search);
$regex = $search . '|' . str_replace(' ', '|', $search);

$html = preg_replace('/\b(' . $regex . ')\b/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);

echo $html; // Outputs: Hello, there is <strong>foo</strong>, after there is <strong>bar</strong> but now I need <strong>foo bar blah</strong>.
```

Comment: Yes, but is I have more than 2 words it become impossible : '/(first|second|third|first second|second first|first third .....)/'

Comment: @user1974375 can you provide more examples of the input and output you want? This will work for what you currently have asked.

Comment: Yes, for example : terms as "apartment" "2 rooms" "3 rooms" "2 rooms apartment" "apartment 2 rooms"

Comment: @user1974375 see edit, it will build the regex based on the search string.

Comment: Yeah ! thanks this will works too. Thanks for your help, have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

Here we are:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(foo|bar)( (foo|bar))*/', '<strong>$0</strong>', $string);
```

Less readable but slightly more efficient (non-capturing groups):

```
$html = preg_replace('/(?:foo|bar)(?: (?:foo|bar))*/', '<strong>$0</strong>', $string);
```

Maybe there's a solution to not repeat `(foo|bar)`...

Ha, and don't forget the `\b`'s or like, if you don't want to match in "arfooo" ;-)

edit: if you need something more dynamic, thanks to **cryptic ツ** for the idea:

```
$words = array('foo', 'bar');

// require PHP 5.3, not very efficient code
$escaped_words = array_map(function ($word) {
    return preg_quote($word, '/');
}, $words);

$pattern = '(?:' . implode('|', $escaped_words) . ')';

$html = preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'(?: '.$pattern.')*/', '<strong>$0</strong>', $string);
```

Comment: This is the right answer, and it can be used with more that two words.

Comment: Like that : '/\b(?:foo|bar)(?: (?:foo|bar))\b*/' ?

Comment: Almost, look at the end: `/\b(?:foo|bar)(?: (?:foo|bar))*\b/`

Comment: Yes thanks. Finaly, I mixed your 2 solutions. I used an array, and I put : '/\b(?:'.implode('|', $possibleValues).')(?: (?:'.implode('|', $possibleValues).'))*\b/i' for the regex. Nice job thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Hello, there is foo, after there is bar but now I need foo bar.';
$string.= ' Lets throw a bar foo in there as well!';

$html = preg_replace('/(bar foo|foo bar|foo|bar)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);

echo $html;
```